# HTML filter with Option tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Does someone know how to do this for option instead of button?
The script should filter the HTML section. My problem is that apparently it doesn´t work with `<option>` instead of `<button>`. Results in not showing me anything instead of the all class.

CSS

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}
.filterDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

This is the filter section. By default it should be set on all

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12" id="myBtnContainer">
    <div class="release-filter justify-content-end d-flex">
            <div class="filter-title">
                <select name="year">
                    <option class="btn active" value="" onclick="filterSelection('all')" disabled selected>Filter By Year</option>
                    <option class="btn" value="2023" onclick="filterSelection('2023')">2023</option>
                    <option class="btn" value="2022" onclick="filterSelection('2022')">2022</option>
                    <option class="btn" value="2021" onclick="filterSelection('2021')">2021</option>
                    <option class="btn" value="2020" onclick="filterSelection('2020')">2020</option>
                  </select>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is one of the items that should be filtered. But as mentioned above it doesn't work. It simply doesn't filter anything and ends up in not showing me anything.

```html
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-12 filterDiv 2023">
    <div class="collection-release">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```js
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
   var i, arr1, arr2;
   arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
   arr2 = name.split(" ");
   for (i = 0; i \< arr2.length; i++) {
      if (arr1.indexOf(arr2\[i\]) == -1) {
         element.className += " " + arr2\[i\];
      }
   }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
   var i, arr1, arr2;
   arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
   arr2 = name.split(" ");
   for (i = 0; i \< arr2.length; i++) {
      while (arr1.indexOf(arr2\[i\]) \> -1) {
         arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2\[i\]), 1);
      }
   }
   element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i \< btns.length; i++) {
   btns\[i\].addEventListener("click", function() {
   var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
   current\[0\].className = current\[0\].className.replace(" active", "");
   this.className += " active";
   });
}
\</script\>
```

Comment: Please fix the big pile of extra ```\``` characters that have ended up in your code and convert it to [a live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: 1. Calling `filterSelection` before defining it will cause an error.
2. What is with all the escaping characters?
3. Please update your question with a `snippet` and tell us how it should behave in more detail.

Comment: Do not use a `click` handler on option elements, that has poor browser support. Use a `change` handler on the select element itself instead.

Comment: Using variable names like x,c,arr1,arr2 makes the code very difficult to understand. If you can add more meaningful names and comment lines, we have a better chance of helping.

Comment: Its basically this code here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_elements it just doesn´t work with option tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the code so that whichever year the user chooses, the div for that year will be visible on the screen, and the others will be hidden. I hope it helps.

```js
var mySelect = document.getElementById('yearSelect');
 mySelect.onchange = (event) => { //catch select option changes.
     var inputText = event.target.value; // get selected option value.

  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (inputText == "all") inputText = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].classList.contains(inputText)) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
     element.classList.add(name);
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
   element.classList.remove(name);
}

// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
   btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
   current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
   this.className += " active";
   });
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block !important; 
}
.filterDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12" id="myBtnContainer">
    <div class="release-filter justify-content-end d-flex">
            <div class="filter-title">
                <select name="year" id="yearSelect">
                    <option class="btn active" value="" onclick="filterSelection('all')" disabled selected>Filter By Year</option>
                    <option class="btn" value="2023">2023</option>
                    <option class="btn" value="2022">2022</option>
                    <option class="btn" value="2021">2021</option>
                    <option class="btn" value="2020">2020</option>
                  </select>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-12 show filterDiv 2023">
    <div class="collection-release">
    2023 filter div
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-12 show filterDiv 2022">
    <div class="collection-release">
    2022 filter div
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-12 show filterDiv 2021">
    <div class="collection-release">
    2021 filter div
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-12 show filterDiv 2020">
    <div class="collection-release">
    2020 filter div
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works only thing missing is that by default it shows all of them

Comment: It doesn't show any in the initial state, can you test it by clicking the **run code snippet** in my answer?

Comment: FIltering works perfectly fine. But on the initial state it should show all elements. After choosing a year they should get filtered

Comment: I edited it the way you wanted, can you check it again?